# Elements search costs

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've got an array of n elements. Those elements are numbers. What I have to do now is find a lot of them in my array. I will have to make about `sqrt(n)` searches.

What is a better option for me from efficiency point of view?

1. Linear search
2. Array Sorting (lets say in linear time, it is possible when we use RadixSort for example) and then searching the elements with binary-search - `O(logn)`

I've got some intuitions, but I dont know how to check and proof it. Linear search cost is (in worst case) : `O(n) * O(sqrt(n)`). Binary-search after sorting would be `O(n) + O(logn) * O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: why binary search effort would be "O(n) * O(logn)"?

Comment: You could sort the smaller array (the sqrt(n) thing with values to be found), or put it into a hashtable. Then make one linear pass through the big array and do the *reversed* lookup for every element.

Comment: @Hitman47 I think he starts from an unsorted array and he has to sort it I suppose

Comment: hash, O(n) build, O(1) lookup

Comment: Linear search: n^1.5; sorting then binary search: n·log n + n^0.5·log n.

Comment: Yes i start from unsorted array. And i have to sort it, that costs O(n). And Hitman is right. That whole sort-binary-seach operation would be O(n) from sorting and O(sqrt(n)) * O(logn)) from binary search. I guess that now i have to compare this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have two options:

1. Linear search `sqrt(n)` times. Cost is `O(n * sqrt(n))`.
2. Sorting an array in `O(n)` and then binary search `sqrt(n)` times.
   Cost is `O(n + log(n) * sqrt(n))`. `n` is bigger then `log(n) * sqrt(n)` for all positive `n`.   [Proof](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%3E%20logx%2asqrtx).
   Thanks to this, we can write `O(n + log(n) * sqrt(n)) = O(n)`.
   Sorting part is dominating, it's the bottleneck.

So, second approach, for big `n`, should be faster - approximately linear.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to solve your problem:

1. sort and then search
2. just search

Make a table of the complexity and you'll have the solution.
Maybe you could use some tool like this http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/ to compare two coplexities.

Different cases you have:

1. Linear search for sqrt(n) times=  O(n * sqrt(n)).
2. Linear sorting and then binary search sqrt(n) times= O(n) + O(log(n) * sqrt(n)= O(n)

The second one seems to be the most promising.